# Where did the Hood get his powers from?

Tags: thunderbirds

The Hood (Thunderbirds) is well known for his light-up eyes in the series and twisting cuticles in the movie (see images below).  For a science-fiction show/movie, these powers seem surprisingly magical.  Is there any reference *ever* (all materials accepted) to where he got his powers from and the nature of those power (psychology experiment gone wrong!)?

[image: Yellow light-up eyes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His powers are unknown in origin.  It's stated so in [the wikia for The Hood](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hood).

According to the TV and Comics

> Throughout the series, the Hood was shown to be a master of disguise,
>   using various masks to try and discover the secrets of the
>   Thunderbirds machines and carry out various missions. He also
>   possessed strange hypnotic powers of unknown origin, although these
>   abilities were apparently limited to making people carry out simple
>   commands, such as to follow him or put them to sleep. He was also
>   apparently unable to use these powers to acquire information; on one
>   occasion he attempted to force Brains to tell him the location of a
>   lost treasure by burying him up to his neck in sand and sunlight and
>   depriving him of water rather than simply hypnotising him to learn the
>   answer, suggesting that he cannot make people tell him information but
>   simply make them carry out certain actions.

According to the Film

> In the film, the Hood's abilities were changed to telekinesis,
>   allowing him to levitate himself and move objects, although his
>   temporary control of Lady Penelope and Parker's bodies when they
>   attempted to rescue the Tracys suggests that he retained at least some
>   of his old hypnotic powers. However, over-use of these abilities
>   weakened him, and—in a marked contrast to the series—his niece Tin-Tin
>   was also shown to possess these abilities, although she only ever used
>   them to help her friends; she even managed to overpower her uncle in a
>   duel, although he had been weakened by over-using his powers while
>   fighting Alan.

Comment: "suggesting that he cannot make people tell him information but simply make them carry out certain actions." He certainly tries in Trapped in the Sky, from a distance with Kyrano.

Comment: Same with "Desperate Intruder", where it seems as if he succeeds about information from the Lake Anasta expedition ("leaving tomorrow, to make a survey of the temple").

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hood_%28Thunderbirds%29#TV_series) and the [Thunderbirds Wikia](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hood#TV_series) both state that the origin of his powers are unknown (btw, both pages are nearly the same):

> "(...) – remain a mystery, as does the origin of his mysterious hypnotic powers. (...)"

Also, in the "Powers and abilities" section of both pages no mention is made of the origin.